# Reducing space betwen header and main in bootstrap, and section and continer in bootstrap 5 cards

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-cards

I want to reduce space between **header** and **main** in *bootstrap 5 cards class* shown by black line A

And line B which is between *section container* (or  tag) and *class album*.

I am using cards class in bootstrap 5.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As shown in the picture, it has a padding around.

[image]

You can reduce the `padding` of `section` and the space between will be reduced.

We can use [bootstrap spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/) class with it or can user own custom class to decrease the padding.

- p-2 (padding 2 for all sides)
- pt-2 (padding 2 for top)
- pb-2 (padding 2 for bottom)

and the final html will be like

```
<section class="jumbotron text-center pt-2 pb-2">
```

or

```
<section class="jumbotron text-center custom-pading-class">
```

Hope this helps